# PhP adding days/months in case of selected values

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, date

Ok I will try to be explicit, I made a script with a form, I need to introduce some informations like name telephone and here is the interesting thing: Start Date, Number of Months ( In my case 1 month, 6 months and 12 months ) and end date.
I complete the start date with jquery_ui timp stamp and I select my option for how many months and I want to make the End Date like this = Start_Date + x months and store them into my database.
`
    Data inceperii asigurarii:

```
<td>
    <select name="durata">
        <option disabled="disabled">Selecteaza perioada</option>
        <option value="1 luna">1 luna</option>
        <option value="6 luni">6 luni</option>
        <option value="12 luni">12 luni</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td height="40" align="right" valign="top">Data incheieri asigurarii:</td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" name="end_date" /></td>
<td></td>
```

and php

```
$date = $_POST['start_date'];
switch($_POST['durata']){
    case '1 luna':
        $data2 = strtotime(date("d.m.yy", strtotime($date)) . " +30 days");
    break;
    case '6 luni':
        $data2 = strtotime(date("d.m.yy", strtotime($date)) . " +180 days");
    break;
    case '12 luni':
        $data2 = strtotime(date("d.m.yy", strtotime($date)) . " +365 days");
    break;
    default:
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `strtotime(date("d.m.yy", strtotime($date)) . " +180 days");` with `strtotime("+180 days", $date);`
There is no need to add `date()` and next `strtotime()`.

Comment: didn't worked case '6 luni':
$data2 = strtotime($date) . " +180 days"); tryed on 6 months and I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in on this line

Comment: @MarianPavel There was syntax error, but it wasn't hard to fix.. Edited.

Comment: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered here is what I got:Date: 17.10.2013 
End Date: 15552017
How many months: 6 monts

Comment: @MarianPavel Change `$date` to timestamp before passing to `strototime()`. And from that you'll receive timestamp too, so use `date()` to get readable date.